# PHP, file exists: 'con'?

Tags: php, filenames, ntfs, file-exists

I made 2 checks of file name validness (for uploading):

1. Is there another file with the same name?
2. Can a file with this name be created at all?

For (1) I use `file_exists`, for (2) — `fopen` for creating.

```
$dir = '../../images/';
if (file_exists($dir.$name))
{
    ok('alreadyexists', 'true');
}
else
{
    $file = fopen($dir.$name, 'x');
    if (FALSE == $file)
    {
        ok('invalid', 'true');
    }
    else
    {
        fclose($file);
        ok();
    }
}
```

Testing the code above, I tried the name 'con' (AFAIK, under Windows you can't create such files). I supposed it would fail at the second test, but `file_exists` returns true for '../../images/con'! Why?

Comment: I suggest to use `is_writable($dir.$name)` after file the file has been touched / created (file gets saved AFTER fclose). `touch`is also a good approach for initially creating a file and test wether it can be written

Comment: @DanFromGermany If you convert the comment into an answer, I'll accept it, because `is_writable` should be used instead of `file_exists` for the declared purpose.

Comment: LOL. Now 'con' passes thru `is_writable`, but `fopen` generates a warning into the output, instead of returning FALSE. It has to be replaced as well, I'm looking for what )

Comment: `file_exists` should be replaced with `is_writable`, `fopen` with `@fopen` and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `is_writable($dir.$name)` after the file has been touched / created (files get saved AFTER `fclose`). `touch()` is also a good approach for initially creating a file and test wether it can be written.

Could try:

```
touch($dir.$name);

is_writable($dir.$name);

//parse the output of
shell_exec('touch ' . $dir . $name);
// or
exec('touch ' . $dir . $name);
```

Would also be interesting what this prints:

```
filetype($dir.$name);
```

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filetype.php

> There are 7 values that can be returned. Here is a list of them and
>   what each one means block: block special device char: character
>   special device dir: directory fifo: FIFO (named pipe) file: regular
>   file link: symbolic link unknown: unknown file type

```
// also interesting:
stat($dir.$name);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. `con` is historically name of IO-pseudo-device in Windows. You can't create file with such name and system will treat this as already existing file. Think of it as a bit of magic that makes our days beautiful.

Other devices (so, reserved file names) with such property are:

- AUX (console connection)
- NUL (null-device)
- COM1 .. COM9 (serial ports)
- PRN (printer)
- LPT1 .. LPT9 (parallel ports)

Comment: Does the second check make any sense then?

Comment: Which check? You can not use that name. But - no, not because it exists. It's because it's reserved by system

Comment: `fopen` check. I have to separate real existing file conflicts from aux/con/nul etc errors (of course, I know what they are, I'm just wondering, while they are interpreted by PHP as existing files, especially in absolute path form).

Comment: PHP does not any magic (well, normally). So it relies on information that FS (file system) is reporting to it. And FS is managed by OS - therefore, PHP will treat such file as existing. So you may use `file_exists()` for such issues